# Effect of projectile movement inside the coil launcher

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, simulations

I'm simulating a simple coil launcher system where there is a round coil , a capacitor and a round projectile which at first is placed at the start of the coil.

so the whole circuit is a simple RLC circuit.
I've simulated the launch with python and FEMM software, the simplified algorithm is:

```
c_voltage = CAP_INIT_VOLTAGE
current = 0
velocity = 0
position = 0
for t in np.arange(0,1,TS):
    voltage_across_coil = c_voltage - (current * COIL_RES)
    dI = (voltage_across_coil / inductance)
    current += dI * TS
    dv_cap = -current / CAP_CAP
    c_voltage += dv_cap * TS

    force,inductance = femm_analysis(current,position) #calculate force with femm software
    acceleration = force / PROJECTILE_MASS
    velocity += acceleration * TS
    projectile_pos += velocity * TS

    #logging velocity here
```

I have designed this system in real world and the simulations seem to be nearly correct.
However, there is a small problem . As I haven't calculated the effect of movement of the projectile on the coil. I mean there is no difference between this simulation and an RLC circuit where there is no moving projectile inside the coil. But I think that effect is relatively small and doesn't make too difference in simulations.

Another way that we can think of it is :

In this simulation the capacitor is charged to some amount that discharges before the projectile reaches the center of the coil. So the coil doesn't pull the projectile back and projectile continues to move forward.

Therefore, I know that some of energy stored in the capacitor will convert to the kinetic energy of projectile ( its around 1.5% in my calculations), but in this simulation all of the capacitor's energy is converted to heat.

Now my question is how should I take that effect into account ?